# How to find the tangent lines of a parabola which must pass through a point without calculus.

Tags: quadratics, tangent-line

I‘m tutoring a student who doesn’t know calculus (yet). I was given the following question:

Find all lines of tangency of the graph $y=x^2$ which pass through the point $P(-6,-5)$.

I know I have to use $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$, but I end up with too many unknown variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've answered a very similar question question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2833210/ .

Comment: [Joachimsthal notations](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) give $((-5)-(-6)^2)(y-x^2)-((y+(-5))/2-(-6)x)^2=\\5\cdot((x+6)-\frac{6+\sqrt{41}}{10}(y+5))\cdot((x+6)-\frac{6-\sqrt{41}}{10}(y+5))=\\ (-\frac14)\cdot((y+5)-(2 (-6+\sqrt{41}))(x+6))\cdot\\((y+5)-(2 (-6-\sqrt{41}))(x+6))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the line be $y+6 = m(x+5)$.

Then, as you are implying, the graph of $y=x^2 - (m(x+6) - 5)$ should be tangent to the $x$-axis, so its vertex should happen at $y=0$.

This equation rewrites as $y = x^2 - mx + (5-6m)$.

Putting this parabola in vertex form gives us $\displaystyle y = x^2 - mx + \frac{m^2}{4}+(5-6m-\frac{m^2}{4})$

From this, we see that the solutions for $m$ are those where $\displaystyle 5-6m-\frac{m^2}{4}=0$

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The equation of the line throught $P$ is:
$$y=mx+6m-5$$
Equating with$y=x^2$:
$$x^2-mx-6m+5=0\implies x=\frac{m\pm \sqrt{m^2-4\cdot(5-6m)}}{2}$$
To be tangent, discriminant has to be $0$:
$$m^2+24m-20=0$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!